# Why doesn't the result of input() match what I expect to get?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Code runs.  But for some reason when I am prompted to enter Sam, I get back "Your name isn't Sam."

```
name = ["Sam"]
print ("What is your name?")
name_choice = input("Type Here: ")

if name == "Sam":
   print ("Your name is Sam")
else:
   print ("Your name isn't Sam")
```

I am working in Python 3.2.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be using `name_choice` here instead of `name`

```
if name == "Sam":
    print ("Your name is Sam")
```

What is the `name` variable meant for anyway?

A good tip when something like this happens is to print the things you are comparing right before the `if`

eg

```
print ("name ==", name)
if name == "Sam":
    print ("Your name is Sam")
```

This would have made it apparent that you are comparing a list to a string

Answer (score 3):

The user input is in variable `name_choice`, but you compare `name` to "Sam" (so the user input is **never** used).

And you are also comparing a string to a list, this will always be `False`

```
In [32]: name = ['Sam']

In [33]: 'Sam' == name
Out[33]: False
```

causing the program to always display "Your name isn't Sam", regardless of what the user entered.

```
if name_choice == 'Sam':
   print ("Your name is Sam")
else:
   print ("Your name isn't Sam")
```

is probably what you want to do

Answer (score 2):

OK, I'll bite, this is a slightly better question. You have a two main issues here.

- Why are you assigning name a list containing only `"Sam"`? What is this meant to achieve?
- You then assign your user input to the variable `name_choice`, which never gets used.

I'm not really sure what your thought process is here - and I think it shows a pretty clear lack of basic knowledge of the language, I'd suggest reading [a tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=python+tutorial).

It's also worth noting that it's a a little pointless to print the user prompt, then use the actual prompt for `"Type Here:"`.

Comment: Any reason I got a downvote on this?

Answer (score 1):

This is because `name == ["Sam"]` (You set it equal to that in the first line) and `"Sam" != ["Sam"]`. You are trying to compare a list to a string.

Also, you probably want to do `if name_choice == "Sam"`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, not sure if this was intentional), `name = ["Sam"]` creates a list of one string element `"Sam"`, which is not the same as a string `"Sam"`

Then you compare this list to a single string, instead of comparing the inputted value to a string (or maybe an element of the list)